# Kernel of projective module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $f \colon M \to N$ is a homomorphism of R-modules such that M, N and N/im(f) are projective. Is is true that ker(f) is projective?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N$ and $N/\operatorname{Im}f$ are projective, the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow \operatorname{Im}f\longrightarrow N \longrightarrow N/\operatorname{Im}f\longrightarrow 0 $$
splits, so $\operatorname{Im}f$ is a direct summand of the projective module $N$ and therefore is projective.

Can you prove similarly that $\ker f$ is projective?

Comment: yep, just look now at the s.e.s.: $$0\to \ker(f) \hookrightarrow M \to im (f)$$ and repeat the argument (you use for similar reasons projective reolutions)